# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Double' with an argument list of type '(String?)'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, int

I have two issues:

```
let amount:String? = amountTF.text
```

1. `amount?.characters.count <= 0`

It's giving error :

```
Binary operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String.CharacterView.IndexDistance?' (aka 'Optional<Int>') and 'In
```

2. `let am = Double(amount)`

It's giving error:

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Double' with an argument list of type '(String?)'
```

I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`amount?.count <= 0` here amount is optional. You have to make sure it not `nil`.

```
let amount:String? = amountTF.text
if let amountValue = amount, amountValue.count <= 0 {

}
```

`amountValue.count <= 0` will only be called if `amount` is not nil.

Same issue for this `let am = Double(amount)`. `amount` is optional.

```
if let amountValue = amount, let am = Double(amountValue) {
       // am  
}
```

Comment: characters has been deprecated = use if let amountValue = amount, !amountValue.isEmpty {...}

Answer (score 8):

Your string is optional because it had a '?", means it could be nil, means further methods would not work. You have to make sure that optional amount exists then use it:

**WAY 1:**

```
// If amount is not nil, you can use it inside this if block.

if let amount = amount as? String {

    let am = Double(amount)
}
```

**WAY 2:**

```
// If amount is nil, compiler won't go further from this point.

guard let amount = amount as? String else { return }

let am = Double(amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for the error is **amount** it should not be null

```
let am = Double(amount!)
```

with check contol

```
if amount != nil {
   let am = Double(amount!)
}
```

Comment: Do not use this. " ! " should never be used as a senior developer. This will lead to incalculable crashes here or there. Optionals are meant to be optional where you write your code if an optional is available and where you go with another way when it is not available. See my answer above, where we check if an optional is available. Then you have to think what to do if it is not available. Using ( ! ) not only leads to crashes but also narrows your vision while thinking of the architecture. Never use ( ! ) anywhere.

Comment: My solution solves the problem. The solution method is debatable, but if that wasn't true, Apple wouldn't allow it anyway. It can be considered as a null check beforehand.

Comment: No. "Apple wouldn't allow it" you are a programmer, Apple let's you write good or bad code. What's suggested above is a common bad approach.