# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(RemoteConfigValue)'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get a string (inside an object) on Firebase (using Swift)

```
let currentDocument = db.collection("countries").document("United States")

        currentDocument.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                let cities = document.data()!["cities"] as? [AnyObject] // This grabs data from a Firebase object named `cities`, inside the object there are arrays that have two pieces of data (e.g. ["cityName" : "New York", "currentTemperature" : 38])
                for i in 0..<cities!.count {
                    let cityName = String(cities![i]["cityName"]!) // Here is where I get the error `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(RemoteConfigValue)'`
                }
            } else {
                print("Document does not exist")

            }
        }
```

After searching this error, the normal solutions I found are similar to [these ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46989131/cannot-invoke-initializer-for-type-double-with-an-argument-list-of-type-stri)

But even after applying those solutions, for example:

```
if let cityName = cities![i]["cityName"]! as? String {
  print(cityName)
}
```

I still get an error like `Cast from 'RemoteConfigValue' to unrelated type 'String' always fails`

How do I solve this?

Comment: First, you don't need to be using RemoteConfigValue with the code or task presented in the question. Second, please include a screenshot of your FireStore structure and a clearer explanation of what you're trying to do. Until we have that, answers are going to send you all directions that may not be correct for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseremoteconfig/api/reference/Classes/RemoteConfigValue)

> `class RemoteConfigValue : NSObject, NSCopying`
>
> This class provides a wrapper for Remote Config parameter values, with methods to get parameter values as different data types.

So you have to write something like this

```
if let cities = document.data()!["cities"] as? [[String:Any]] { // cities is obviously an array of dictionaries
   for city in cities { // don't use index based loops if you actually don't need the index
       if let cityName = city["cityName"] as? RemoteConfigValue {
          print(cityName.stringValue)
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work but I don't understand why? The logic seems good and if I do `print(city)` it will print just fine... But everything else returns nil

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let currentDocument = db.collection("countries").document("United States")

        currentDocument.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                let cities = document.data()!["cities"] // This grabs data from a Firebase object named `cities`, inside the object there are arrays that have two pieces of data (e.g. ["cityName" : "New York", "currentTemperature" : 38])
                for i in 0..<cities!.count {
                    if let cityName = cities[i]["cityName"]! as? String {
                      print(cityName)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("Document does not exist")

            }
        }
```